# Dell inspiron 7591 in-build microphone not working

Tags: sound, release-hera, dell

I am having problems with internal microphone on elementary OS 5.1 Hera(based on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS). Linux is not detecting the internal microphone. If I plugin a headphone with microphone, it will be working fine. Also there is no problem with the internal speakers.

`sudo pavucontrol`

[image: screenshot]

I have tried all the methods specified [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/).

Also I have tried editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` with `options snd-hda-intel model=dell` which didn't worked as well.

Following are the output for `head -n 1 /proc/asound/card0/codec*`:

```
==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
    Codec: Realtek ALC3254

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#2 <==
    Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
```

Here is my [Alsa logs](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=ec23cfc4bddc6d77ea1a51c2c6e7aceb7aec95d1).

Do anyone have any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Your kernel is up to date with version 5?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the kernel as well

Comment: I can confirm the issue on Dell Inspiron 7590 with Ubuntu 18.04